# Category isn't this unless property is false

Tags: c#, linq, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, booleanquery

As the title describes. I am stuck, an otherwise simple use of and, xor, or expressions in a LINQ statement.

```
from s in db.Items
where <Other boolean operations> &&
      s.Category.Contains("something") &&
      s.IsReviewed == false
```

Where I want the other boolean operations to filter the list down, and where the remainder of items should not be of the category "something" unless the IsReviewed bool is false.

An alternate way to express this is:
I want items of any category to show, except "something" category unless it hasn't been reviewed.

Your direction is appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you want all filtered items to be `IsReviewed` if they are not in `Category.Contains("something")` and `!IsReviewed` if they are in `Category.Contains("something")`? Or do you not care the state of `IsReviewed` if the item is not in category?

Comment: I want all filtered items to be "IsReviewed" bool agnostic (true or false), unless it is of the category "something", for them I only want those that are false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer to reflect logic according to your comment.

```
from s in db.Items
where <Other boolean operations> &&
      (!s.Category.Contains("something") || s.IsReviewed == false)
```

Comment: @CAD.Dev Do you have any other categories?  Do they meet all of your other criteria?

Comment: Yes, there are many other categories. Where I would like to show both reviewed and unreviewed items.

Comment: @CAD.Dev Updated answer.

Comment: @CAD.Dev Then they would have passed the criteria as originally shown.  If they weren't being shown, then they either didn't exist, or didn't pass your other criteria.

Comment: @VenkatPasumarthi The change is semantically identical.  It will never produce a different result than the previous revision.

Comment: @Servy Right again

Comment: @CAD.Dev This should work exactly as you described. Qualifies all scenarios you mentioned here:
IF NOT "Something" IS True
IF "Something" && Unreviewed IS True
IF "Something" && Reviewed IS False

Comment: There are now two semantically identical solutions. Thank you for your help. This works!

Answer (score 1):

Based on all the comments I am understanding you are looking for all items that aren't in `Category.Contains("something")` or the ones that are if they are `!IsReviewed`

```
from s in db.Items
where <Other boolean operations> &&
      (!s.Category.Contains("something") || !s.IsReviewed)
```

You can move the negation around so you are excluding any items that are in `Category.Contains("something")` and are `IsReviewed`

```
from s in db.Items
where <Other boolean operations> &&
      !(s.Category.Contains("something") && s.IsReviewed)
```

Comment: I feel like this is the correct answer: i am looking for Not(category = "something" and isReviewed = true)

Comment: If I could choose two answers, I would.

Answer (score -1):

So you want all of the items where the category is NOT "something" OR `IsReviewed` is false.

Comment: Can you add this as a comment? Rather than an answer?

Comment: @CAD.Dev It's an answer to the question, not a comment, so...no.

Comment: @Servy: Does the added code illustrate what you were saying?